# how to capture this site for use PhantomJsDriver and Selenium(Java)

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

i try to site(https://m.naver.com) capture.

i used code is

```
String cli_args[] = new String[]{
    "--web-security=false",
    "--ssl-protocol=any",
    "--ignore-ssl-errors=true",
    "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE"
};

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0");
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cli_args);
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");

PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).setScriptTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("https://m.naver.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav']/div[3]/nav/ul/li[2]/a")).click();

new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='nmap_news_1']")));
(this Wait is Work Fine)

new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='nmap_news_1']/a")));
(this Wait is Work - NOT FOUND. GAVE UP Error)

new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='nmap_news_1']/a/span/img")));
(this Wait is Work - NOT FOUND. GAVE UP Error)
```

It works well but suddenly it does not work properly.

The element I'm looking for is the html element below.

```html
<div id="nmap_news_1" class="ad" data-unit="1120D" data-tb="NEWS_1" data-extra="" data-mdom-unit="1120H" data-mdom="true" data-dom-url="http://mv.ad.naver.com/adshow" data-da-revision="161128111917755" data-position-type="rel" data-position-index="0" data-position-computed-index="7">
  <a href="https://mv.ad.naver.com/adclick?unit=1120D&amp;ac=7329029&amp;src=2999084&amp;br=2390035&amp;tb=NEWS_1&amp;rk=WDvymwpgE9kAAJjTh8AAAAQY&amp;eltts=0e%2F4bxL0hwyB3qHjBRDDRQ%3D%3D&amp;x_dy=1276&amp;x_ih=736&amp;x_th=85&amp;x_iv=0" style="display:block;background:#fff;text-decoration:none;">
    <span id="nbp_da_img" style="display:block;width:100%;height:85px;background:url(https://ssl.pstatic.net/tveta/libs/1148/1148810/20160929180724-bkVaw4AG_bg_left.jpg) repeat-x;background-size:auto 85px;-webkit-background-size:1px 85px;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;font-size:0;">
      <img src="https://ssl.pstatic.net/tveta/libs/1148/1148810/20160929180724-bkVaw4AG.jpg" alt="AD" width="320" height="85" data-media-width="640" data-media-height="170" data-content-type="image" data-bakery="material" style="vertical-align:top;border:none" onload="naver_corp_da.logParamManager['nmap_news_1'].imgOnloadHandler();">&nbsp;
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

But strangely, it does not display properly, it is displayed as below.

```html
<div id="nmap_news_1" class="ad ready" data-unit="1120D" data-tb="NEWS_1" data-extra="" data-mdom-unit="1120H" data-mdom="true" data-dom-url="http://mv.ad.naver.com/adshow" data-da-revision="161128111917755" data-position-type="rel" data-position-index="0" data-position-computed-index="7">
  <span class="ad_load"></span>
</div>
```

I think this is a script execution error, but I can not find a solution.
Could you please help me with the code to get elements on the site?

Using a translator can make a word strange.
Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: how do you define "suddenly "? did you change selenium or java or phantomjs versions? Or the server updated? what is the error that you are getting? NoSuchElement? do you want to apply the WaitFor on the latest HTML? Or make the latest HTML code as per the old? please clarify

Comment: It seems that the javascript loading of the site does not work properly.

Comment: Could you test it with my code?